# Handle deleted MQTT topics with MappingJackson2MessageConverter

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

In a customized `IntegrationFlow`, I use `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` for subscriptions to generate corresponding POJOs from JSON. This works perfectly so far.

However, some topics are retained and can be deleted. This currently leads to an exception:

```
ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler [MQTT Call: ...]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: failed to transform message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={...}]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:119)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (byte[])""; line: 1, column: 0], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[0], headers={...}]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:185)
    ...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (byte[])""; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4916)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4818)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3866)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:221)
    ...
```

Is there any way to intercept this case and process the deleted topic from the header? I could easily live with getting `null` as a result. However, as this is not possible with messaging because it would terminate the flow, I am looking for an alternative solution. Would `routeByException()` be an option or is there a better solution?

My setup looks more or less like this:

```java
    <T> IntegrationFlowRegistration subscriber(
            final MqttConnectionOptions options,
            final String id,
            final String topic,
            final Class<T> type,
            final Class<?> view,
            final GenericHandler<T> handler
    ) {
        final var adapter = new Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(options, id, topic);
        final IntegrationFlowBuilder builder = IntegrationFlow
                .from(adapter)
                .transform(new PojoTransformer<>(type, view))
                .handle(handler);
        return this.flowContext.registration(builder.get()).register();
    }


    public class PojoTransformer<T> extends AbstractTransformer {
        private final Class<T> type;
        private final Class<?> view;


        public PojoTransformer(
                final Class<T> type,
                final Class<?> view
        ) {
            this.type = type;
            this.view = view;
        }


        @Override
        protected Object doTransform(final Message<?> message) {
            // final Object o = message.getPayload();
            // if (o instanceof final byte[] bytes && bytes.length == 0 || o instanceof final String s && s.isBlank()) {
            //  return null;
            // }
            return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter().fromMessage(message, this.type, this.view);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came finally up with basically something like this:

```java
<T> IntegrationFlowRegistration subscriber(
        final MqttConnectionOptions options,
        final String id,
        final String topic,
        final Class<T> type,
        final Class<?> view,
        final GenericHandler<T> handler,
        final Consumer<MessageHeaders> onDeletion
) {
    final var adapter = new Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(options, id, topic);
    final IntegrationFlowBuilder builder = IntegrationFlow
            .from(adapter)
            .route(byte[].class, payload -> payload.length == 0, spec -> spec
                    .subFlowMapping(true, flow -> flow.handle((p, h) -> {
                        onDeletion.accept(h);
                        return null;
                    }))
                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
            )
            .transform(new PojoTransformer<>(type, view))
            .handle(handler);
    return this.flowContext.registration(builder.get()).register();
}
```

Nevertheless, I am still interested in other and possibly more elegant solutions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You may use a `filter()` instead of router. I see that you mean that in your case the payload is an empty `byte[]`, so the plain `<byte[]>filter(payload -> payload.length != 0)` should be enough.

Comment: I should have emphasized, that I do have to take some action in this case and need to process the received header. So a filter wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like your `.transform(new PojoTransformer<>(type, view))` throws an exception in case of invalid JSON.

Consider to use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with a `trapException = true` option to not re-throw that exception and use some `failureChannel` to handle that exception from this transformer.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice

Comment: Thanks Artem for responding. I actually do use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to pass any exception to a logger. That's how I spot it. So, the exception itself was handled.

But as I try to not use exceptions for control flow if possible I finally came up with
`.route(Message.class, MqttFlowConfiguration::hasEmptyPayload, sf -> ...)` where `hasEmptyPayload` reads as `return p instanceof final byte[] bytes && bytes.length == 0 || p instanceof final String s && s.isBlank();` So, this should be fine I think. Anything against this approach?

Comment: On a higher level, for me the question arises, if this is something which should be handled by SI for example with an additional `MqttIntegrationEvent`. AFAIK empty payloads are valid, at least for clearing retained topics. And this exactly my use case, which I have to deal with in my application. Nothing urgent as I found a solution but maybe something to consider.

Comment: I am still wondering, if this is something SI could/should handle. Would it make sense to raise a new let's say `MqttTopicRemovedEvent` within `AbstractMqttMessageDrivenChannelAdapter#messageArrived()` holding the `MessageHeaders` when thy payload is empty? If so, I would raise an issue and prepare a PR once I will find some time.

Comment: No it does not. This feels more like a target application business logic. I'm not sure that all MQTT brokers send an empty messages to consumers when topic is removed...

Comment: Well, at least it is specified for both [MQTT 3.1.1 `[MQTT-3.3.1-10]`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) and [MQTT 5.0 `[MQTT-3.3.1-6]`](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.html)